# problem with event propagation in FireFox

Tags: jquery, event-propagation

I'm using the following code to prevent event propagation:

```
function mapSlider(e) {
if ($('.slideme').hasClass('open')) {
        $('.slideme').animate({left:0,},'slow').removeClass('open');
        $('.opened').hide();
        $('.closed').show();
        } else {
        $('.slideme').animate({left:-710,},'slow').addClass('open');
        $('.opened').show();
        $('.closed').hide();
        }
        return(false);

        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

It's working in Chrome and Safari but not Opera or Firefox (haven't even attempted IE yet!). FF firebug says 'e' is undefined. I'm nowhere near being a jquery guru and I don't understand why e is undefined, but is it really? I thought var e *is* defining it?

And how do I go about fixing it?

Apologies for stupid questions - I'm self-taught and pick things up as I go.

MTIA

Comment: <div id="map-box" class="slideme" onClick="mapSlider()">

Comment: just to save you 2 lines of code: $('.opened, .closed').toggle();

Comment: Yeah, I knew someone would pull me up on that :-) Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery unifies all these browser differences. You just have to do:

```
function mapSlider(e) {
    if ($('.slideme').hasClass('open')) {
        $('.slideme').animate({left:0,},'slow').removeClass('open');
        $('.opened').hide();
        $('.closed').show();
    } else {
        $('.slideme').animate({left:-710,},'slow').addClass('open');
        $('.opened').show();
        $('.closed').hide();
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

In your example, the code at the bottom would never be executed anyway, as you do a `return false;` before.

Now it just depends on *how* this function is called. If you assign it properly as an event handler, then the event object is automatically passed.

**Update:**

In your code, you are not passing the `event` object to your handler. You have to do:

```
<div id="map-box" class="slideme" onClick="mapSlider(event)">
```

but I think this does not work in IE.

So it is **better** to do it the jQuery way:

```
$(function() {
    $('#map-box').click(mapSlider);
});
```

---

The [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) is pretty good, I recommend reading it. Especially in this case about [the **`Event`** object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Also have a look at this [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery).

Comment: Thanks Felix. Function is called:`<div id="map-box" class="slideme" onClick="mapSlider()">`. I tried it with only the 2 lines you suggested, but it then stops working in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @circey: Have you also attached the event handler like I showed in my update. You have to do it, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: The problem is that the entire window has been coded with an onclick event thing, so any additional jquery I put in the window is firing both events when the user clicks on #map-box. Yeah, it's probably really bad to do something like this but the site is in the style of comicsanscriminal.com and the entire site scrolls vertically onclick.

Comment: @circey: You have to remove the `onclick` thing from your HTML. Or if you cannot do this, do it like `<div id="map-box" class="slideme" onClick="mapSlider(event || window.event)">`. Although you should always use jQuery if you are already using it anyway. Using `onclick` in HTML is very... old school ;)

Comment: Okay I tried your suggestion in your update and that's fixed the problem in Opera, so now it's only FF not working! and probably IE..

Comment: Oh geez. Made a stupid mistake, found it, fixed it, and now it works perfectly in all browsers using just your two lines to stop propagation! Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No code after return false will be executed.
move return false to the last line of your function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I did it, but it didn't fix the FF & Safari problem.

Comment: you need to remove the onclick property and attach an event lister using `$('#map-box').click(mapSlider);` in order to pass the event argument to your function.